# When does error "expression must have pointer type" occur?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, compiler-errors

I have a source code that gives the error "expression must have pointer type"

It is legacy code and I do not have the whole code. The code on which the error comes is:

```
(void *)&arr[0]
```

I do not know the type of `arr`.

1. On what conditions can this error occur?
2. What type of `arr` could be causing this error?

I know the data is less to determine the issue but I need to emulate it in smaller code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The real mystery is why this code (presumably) worked at one time. What context was this legacy code from? Maybe it was in some 16-bit system in which someone was treating unsigned ints as pointers -- although I would think that would give a warning rather than an outright error in compilation.

Comment: "I do not know the type of `arr`..." - how is that possible? If you have the source code, why can't you just look at how `arr` is declared and figure out its type? That will immediately make it clear what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "need to emulate it in smaller code", here is an example

```
int main() {
  int arr;
  (void *)&arr[0];
}
```

Variable `arr` declared with type `int` causes this error. In fact, `arr` of any non-array non-pointer type will cause this error.

Comment: Thanks but this does not produce the exact error, it says: "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"... sorry but i need the exact error.

Comment: @Anuj Priyadarshi: Er.. What compiler are you using? C does not have "exact errors". Each compiler reports errors in its own way. Error message  "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer..." is what GCC compiler produces in such cases. Your original "expression must have pointer type” is *not* a GCC error message. It is pointless to try to reproduce the exact text of error message by using a *different* compiler. What compiler produced the original message? It actually sounds like MSVC error message.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when `arr` doesn't have pointer or array type. Any type of `arr` except an array or pointer type causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

"I do not know the type of `arr`."

Well, you **do know** what it is not: a pointer. Therefore the error.

Bad news are: without further information, it is not possible to fix that.

Comment: @JAL: It answers both "parts" of the question: 1) is actually included in 2) which I answered by negation, as it is too broad for a positive answer,

Answer (score 0):

In order for the expression `arr[0]` to be legal, `arr` *must* be either an array or pointer type.  Remember that postfix operators such as `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators like `&`, so the whole expression parses as `(void *) (&(arr[0]))`; that is, we take the address of the *result* of `arr[0]` and cast it to `void *`.